# iOS write UIImageJPEGRepresentation to png format

Tags: ios, uiimage

I used `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get the `NSData` but the file extension is `.png`.

e.g.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, compression);
[imageData writeToFile:@"abc.png" atomically:YES];
```

It worked, although I am not sure what I am getting. I mean is the final file still a `.png` file? If I use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` would it make a difference? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, you'll write the data in JPEG format.

Using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` will write the data in PNG format.

The extension you specify only affects what applications a user might open the file in. There's no good reason to write JPEG data to a file with a `.png` extension.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. So by what I did it would be same to simply renaming a jpg format file to png format file?